# Are (or have been) goblins ever associated with anti-semitic characteristics?

Tags: folklore

Some characteristics used to describe goblins are also depicted in anti-semitic propaganda (they are usually described as greedy, hook nosed creatures).

Were goblins ever been associated with antisemitism in some way?

Comment: Wagner's Nibelungs have sometimes been interpreted as an antisemitic trope.

Comment: https://t.co/bt6JkPxHQo (I copied this link from a Twitter post, but it redirects) evidence of antisemitism in goblins

Answer (score 0):

A example can be seen in the poem Goblin Market, where goblins are the bankers and have pointed noses, long fingers and greed. In the early 20th century, these characteristics appeared in antisemitic caricatures and they became synonimous with antisemitism in general.

Comment: The Wiki article doesn't go into detail here. Were these characteristics already in place when the Goblin Market was written?